# How to write Oracle query to find a total length of possible overlapping from-to dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling to find the query for the following task

I have the following data and want to find the total network day for each unique ID

```
ID  From        To          NetworkDay
1   03-Sep-12   07-Sep-12   5
1   03-Sep-12   04-Sep-12   2
1   05-Sep-12   06-Sep-12   2
1   06-Sep-12   12-Sep-12   5
1   31-Aug-12   04-Sep-12   3
2   04-Sep-12   06-Sep-12   3
2   11-Sep-12   13-Sep-12   3
2   05-Sep-12   08-Sep-12   3
```

Problem is the date range can be overlapping and I can't come up with SQL that will give me the following results

```
ID  From        To          NetworkDay
1   31-Aug-12   12-Sep-12   9
2   04-Sep-12   08-Sep-12   4
2   11-Sep-12   13-Sep-12   3
```

and then

```
ID  Total Network Day
1   9
2   7
```

In case the network day calculation is not possible just get to the second table would be sufficient.

Hope my question is clear

Comment: What are the rules for merging the ranges?  For example how do you know that 04-Sep-12 to 08-Sep-12 should be 4 days and not 5?  I'm guessing it has something to do with weekends days not counting?

Comment: Hi Andrews, you're correct the idea is to exclude weekends. However, that part isn't very crucial because I can calculate that later on if I get the second table.

Comment: So we can ignore the NetworkDay column values when getting the first table results?  The second results table is trivial: `select id, sum(networkday) from first_table group by id` isn't it?

Comment: No because I do not want to double count the overlapping part. The query above will get 9 network days for ID 2 because it will count 5-Sep and 6-Sep twice (5 and 6 Sep are overlapping in the first and last rows of ID 2

Comment: @Roby: you can use the method described this a related question to build continuous date ranges: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109331/how-to-select-the-first-continous-group-of-rows-using-oracle-sql

Comment: @Roby do you need to do this in a single query or do you have the opportunity to use custom packages or functions.

Comment: @Vincent I will try to adapt that

Answer (score 2):

We can use Oracle Analytics, namely the "OVER ... PARTITION BY" clause, in Oracle to do this. The PARTITION BY clause is kind of like a GROUP BY but without the aggregation part. That means we can group rows together (i.e. partition them) and them perform an operation on them as separate groups. As we operate on each row we can then access the columns of the previous row above. This is the feature PARTITION BY gives us. (PARTITION BY is not related to partitioning of a table for performance.)

So then how do we output the non-overlapping dates? We first order the query based on the (ID,DFROM) fields, then we use the ID field to make our partitions (row groups). We then test the previous row's TO value and the current rows FROM value for overlap using an expression like: (in pseudo code)

```
 max(previous.DTO, current.DFROM) as DFROM
```

This basic expression will return the original DFROM value if it doesnt overlap, but will return the previous TO value if there is overlap. Since our rows are ordered we only need to be concerned with the last row. In cases where a previous row completely overlaps the current row we want the row then to have a 'zero' date range. So we do the same thing for the DTO field to get:

```
max(previous.DTO, current.DFROM) as DFROM, max(previous.DTO, current.DTO) as DTO
```

Once we have generated the new results set with the adjusted DFROM and DTO values, we can aggregate them up and count the range intervals of DFROM and DTO.

Be aware that most date calculations in database are not inclusive such as your data is. So something like DATEDIFF(dto,dfrom) will not include the day dto actually refers to, so we will want to adjust dto up a day first.

I dont have access to an Oracle server anymore but I know this is possible with the Oracle Analytics. The query should go something like this: 
(Please update my post if you get this to work.)

```
SELECT id, 
    max(dfrom, LAST_VALUE(dto) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dfrom) ) as dfrom, 
    max(dto, LAST_VALUE(dto) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dfrom) ) as dto
  from (
    select id, dfrom, dto+1 as dto from my_sample   -- adjust the table so that dto becomes non-inclusive
      order by id, dfrom
  ) sample;
```

The secret here is the **LAST_VALUE(dto) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dfrom)** expression which returns the value previous to the current row.
So this query should output new dfrom/dto values which dont overlap. It's then a simple matter of sub-querying this doing (dto-dfrom) and sum the totals.

### Using MySQL

I did haves access to a mysql server so I did get it working there. MySQL doesnt have results partitioning (Analytics) like Oracle so we have to use result set variables. This means we use @var:=xxx type expressions to *remember* the last date value and adjust the dfrom/dto according. Same algorithm just a little longer and more complex syntax. We also have to *forget* the last date value any time the ID field changes!

So here is the sample table (same values you have):

```
create table sample(id int, dfrom date, dto date, networkDay int);
insert into sample values
    (1,'2012-09-03','2012-09-07',5),
    (1,'2012-09-03','2012-09-04',2),
    (1,'2012-09-05','2012-09-06',2),
    (1,'2012-09-06','2012-09-12',5),
    (1,'2012-08-31','2012-09-04',3),
    (2,'2012-09-04','2012-09-06',3),
    (2,'2012-09-11','2012-09-13',3),
    (2,'2012-09-05','2012-09-08',3);
```

On to the query, we output the un-grouped result set like above:
The variable @ld is "last date", and the variable @lid is "last id". Anytime @lid changes, we reset @ld to null. FYI In mysql the := operators is where the assignment happens, an = operator is just equals.

This is a 3 level query, but it could be reduced to 2. I went with an extra outer query to keep things more readable. The inner most query is simple and it adjusts the *dto* column to be non-inclusive and does the proper row ordering. The middle query does the adjustment of the dfrom/dto values to make them non-overlapped. The outer query simple drops the non-used fields, and calculate the interval range.

```
set @ldt=null, @lid=null;
select id, no_dfrom as dfrom, no_dto as dto, datediff(no_dto, no_dfrom) as days from (
select if(@lid=id,@ldt,@ldt:=null) as last, dfrom, dto, if(@ldt>=dfrom,@ldt,dfrom) as no_dfrom, if(@ldt>=dto,@ldt,dto) as no_dto, @ldt:=if(@ldt>=dto,@ldt,dto), @lid:=id as id,
        datediff(dto, dfrom) as overlapped_days
  from (select id, dfrom, dto + INTERVAL 1 DAY as dto from sample order by id, dfrom) as sample
  ) as nonoverlapped
  order by id, dfrom;
```

The above query gives the results (notice dfrom/dto are non-overlapping here):

```
+------+------------+------------+------+
| id   | dfrom      | dto        | days |
+------+------------+------------+------+
|    1 | 2012-08-31 | 2012-09-05 |    5 |
|    1 | 2012-09-05 | 2012-09-08 |    3 |
|    1 | 2012-09-08 | 2012-09-08 |    0 |
|    1 | 2012-09-08 | 2012-09-08 |    0 |
|    1 | 2012-09-08 | 2012-09-13 |    5 |
|    2 | 2012-09-04 | 2012-09-07 |    3 |
|    2 | 2012-09-07 | 2012-09-09 |    2 |
|    2 | 2012-09-11 | 2012-09-14 |    3 |
+------+------------+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

How about constructing an SQL which merges intervals by removing holes and considering only maximum intervals. It goes like this (not tested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT F.ID, F.From, L.To
 FROM Temp AS F, Temp AS L
 WHERE F.From < L.To AND F.ID = L.ID
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM Temp AS T
                 WHERE T.ID = F.ID
                 AND F.From < T.From AND T.From < L.To
                         AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                         FROM Temp AS T1
                            WHERE T1.ID = F.ID
                            AND T1.From < T.From
                            AND T.From <= T1.To)
               )
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Temp AS T2
              WHERE T2.ID = F.ID
              AND (
                    (T2.From < F.From AND F.From <= T2.To)
                 OR (T2.From < L.To AND L.To < T2.To)
                   )
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with t_data as (
    select 1 as id,
           to_date('03-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') as start_date,
           to_date('07-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') as end_date from dual
    union all
    select 1,
           to_date('03-sep-12','dd-mon-yy'),
           to_date('04-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
    union all
    select 1,
           to_date('05-sep-12','dd-mon-yy'),
           to_date('06-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
    union all
    select 1,
           to_date('06-sep-12','dd-mon-yy'),
           to_date('12-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
    union all 
    select 1,
           to_date('31-aug-12','dd-mon-yy'),
           to_date('04-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
    union all 
    select 2,
           to_date('04-sep-12','dd-mon-yy'), 
           to_date('06-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
    union all 
    select 2, 
           to_date('11-sep-12','dd-mon-yy'), 
           to_date('13-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
    union all 
    select 2, 
           to_date('05-sep-12','dd-mon-yy'), 
           to_date('08-sep-12','dd-mon-yy') from dual
),
t_holidays as (
    select to_date('01-jan-12','dd-mon-yy') as holiday
      from dual
),
t_data_rn as (
    select rownum as rn, t_data.* from t_data
),
t_model as (
    select distinct id,
           start_date
    from t_data_rn
      model
         partition by (rn, id)
         dimension by (0 as i)
         measures(start_date, end_date)
         rules
         (  start_date[for i 
                      from 1 
                        to end_date[0]-start_date[0]
                 increment 1] = start_date[0] + cv(i),
            end_date[any] = start_date[cv()] + 1
         )
      order by 1,2
),
t_network_days as (
    select t_model.*,
           case when
               mod(to_char(start_date, 'j'), 7) + 1 in (6, 7)
               or t_holidays.holiday is not null               
               then 0 else 1
           end as working_day
      from t_model
      left outer join t_holidays
        on t_holidays.holiday = t_model.start_date
)
select id, 
       sum(working_day) as network_days
  from t_network_days
 group by id;
```

- `t_data` - your initial data
- `t_holidays` - contains list of holidays
- `t_data_rn` - just adds unique key (`rownum`) to each row of `t_data`
- `t_model` - expands `t_data` date ranges into a flat list of dates
- `t_network_days` - marks each date from `t_model` as working day or weekend based on day of week (Sat and Sun) and holidays list
- final query - calculates number of network day per each group.